# Single Borders on horizontal list / menu

Tags: css, list, menu, border

I have a css menu and I can't seem to get the borders right.
The left and right borders of list times are displayed next to each other, My client wants one line between each list item.
Here's a "Fiddle": http://codepen.io/texxs/pen/ndmhq 
Here's a test page (same code looks different when it's actually on a page):
http://devandtestingserver.com/ARS_v2/menu2.html

Thanks

Comment: Please post code, not just links.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
li {border-right: 1px solid #000;}
li:first-child {border-left: 1px solid #000;}
```